# How to deploy NodeJS app that run in HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, https

I need to deploy my app with HTTPS on the same server with Direct Admin

First, I set the port to 8443 and start the server with node index.js.
The server says that it's running on port 8443.
But when I try to access https:// domain . com:8443/socket.io/socket.io.js, the browser return an error message "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

After that, I set the port to 443 (as someone said that HTTPS can only run with port 443) and start the server with sudo node index.js. This time the server did not start and retunr lot of error

> PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js:45
>         let value = keyValueArr[2] || ''
>         ^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class)
>   not yet supported outside strict mode
>       at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>       at Object. (PROJECT_PATH/index.js:16:25)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)

How can I fix this?

Comment: recommend you to put nginx in front of node to handle HTTPS

Comment: Running on 443 (anything under 1024) you need root privileges. Indeed the best practice is to have a reverse proxy doing ssl offload (httpd, nginx, f5,..). For the conn refused - is your certificate trusted?

Comment: I'm using CloudFlare to protect my domains. That was the problem: CloudFlare only allow some predefined ports. I changed the port into one of the port in the allowed list and it works fine. No sudo need so the error about Block-scoped declarations does not happen too :)

Answer (score 0):

You should deploy the reverse proxy(like: nginx) front of node service, all network or https configurations stuff will be process perfectly on that, node webserver just run in internal of server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign parameters. Here is an example code. Hope it will help you.

```
global.__basedir = __dirname;
const http = require("http");
const https = require('https');
const express = require("express");
const fs = require('fs')

const app = express();
let key = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/ssls/key.pem','utf-8');
let cert = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/ssls/cert.pem','utf-8');

const parameters = {
  key: key,
  cert: cert
}

// Create an HTTP service.
http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
// Create an HTTPS service identical to the HTTP service.
https.createServer(parameters, app).listen(8443);
```

Generate a key.pem and cert.pem file under ssls folder in your app's directory.
Then run your application.It will run your nodejs in HTTPS and HTTP.